# How to execute multiple QueryBuilders in a transaction using TypeORM

Tags: sql, orm, typeorm

I have multiple queries that I created using QueryBuilder, I wanted to execute all of these queries inside a single transaction.

I read the documentation but it lacks information on how to use a QueryBuilder with transactions. I tried to create my queries using the same QueryRunner manager but I really feel like this does nothing.

I also tried to wrap my method using a @Transaction decoration but I get a socket hang up error.

This is my current attempt, I only added 2 queries in the example but I have 5 in total.

```typescript
let user, membersInstituition
const connection = getConnection()
const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner()

console.log(queryRunner.isTransactionActive) // false
await queryRunner.startTransaction()
try {
    console.log(queryRunner.isTransactionActive) // true
    user = await queryRunner.manager
        .createQueryBuilder(Usuarios, 'user')
        .leftJoin(UltimaAtualizacaoMobile, 'att', 'user.id_usuario = att.id_usuario')
        .select(['user.id_usuario as idUser, user.nome as name, att.ultima_atualizacao as ultimaAtualizacaoMobile'])
        .where('user.id_usuario = :idUsuario', { idUsuario: idUsuario })
        .execute()

    membersInstituition = await queryRunner.manager
        .createQueryBuilder(Instituicoes, 'insti')
        .leftJoin(Amostras, 'am', 'am.id_instituicao = insti.id_instituicao')
        .leftJoin(MembrosInstituicao, 'mi', 'mi.id_instituicao = insti.id_instituicao')
        .leftJoin(Permissoes, 'perm', 'perm.id_permissao = mi.id_permissao')
        .leftJoin(MembrosAmostra, 'mam', 'mam.id_amostra = am.id_instituicao AND mam.id_membro_instituicao = mi.id_membro_instituicao')
        .where('am.id_amostra IN (:...idAmostras)', { idAmostras: idAmostras })
        .andWhere('mi.id_usuario = :idUsuario', { idUsuario: idUsuario })
        .select('mi.id_membro_instituicao as idMember, mam.id_membro_amostra as idMemberAmostra, insti.id_instituicao as idInstituition, perm.permissao as userPermission')
        .orderBy('insti.id_instituicao', 'ASC')
        .execute()

    await queryRunner.commitTransaction()
    console.log(queryRunner.isTransactionActive) // false
} catch (error) {
    // Handle error
} finally {
    await queryRunner.release()
}
```

Comment: Did you try logging `user` and `membersInstituition` values?

Comment: This is the correct way of using transactions with typeorm. Why do you feel it doesn nothing? You can log all the queries executed with typeorm and see that it does start a transaction.

Comment: I didn't know logging could show when the transaction started/ended. I confirmed the code above is indeed working. Thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above code is indeed working, confirmed using TypeORM's logging, it shows the transaction starting and all the following queries before committing.

More info on how to enable Logging and to verify if your queries are under the same transaction: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/logging.md